# Error "Select at least one membership option" when adding a membership with a price set

Tags: civimember

I'm new to CiviCRM. my version is 4.6.8

The problem happen when I try to add a New Membership. 
I have the following:
Membership Organization and Type    "Organizzation-NAME" - "select" OR "chose price set"

Select Membership Organization and then Membership Type. Alternatively, you can use a price set.

Well When I did not select a Membership type but I chose the price set and add one or more types I can't save because I receive the following message:

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Select at least one membership option.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Not all items in a membership price set are tied to memberships.  That error usually means you selected items without memberships attached.  Could you please include some screenshots of the selection you made as well as the relevant price set options?

Answer (score 1):

While creating the price set option value you need to select the corresponding membership

[image]

If this is not selected then you cannot create an membership using price set

Comment: Hi Jon, Hi Ramesh, thank you both for your replies.
Now I see that I configure a wrong "Input Field Type" for my existing Membership. I used "Text/Numeric Quantity" and even if appear correct to me is not acceptable. Now I'm using "select" and It sems to works.

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to understand if CiviCRM allow me to add membership assign different fee for different users. Ie: I add a payment for a standard fee and a young fee. I would like to associate the standard fee to the parent and the young fee to the sun of my contact. In this way I should be able to understand if all fees where payed along year for all persons belonging to the same family.

Comment: please let me know what are you trying to achieve -- if I am not wrong you need to create two different membership one for parent and one for child -- and you can also create two different price set for both the membership type and you can assign

Comment: OK, after many months without reply I'm still here with the same problem: I'm not able to configure memberships as I need for my association. I'll try to explain better and add some screeshot.

Comment: OK, after many months without reply I'm still here with the same problem: I'm not able to configure memberships as I need for my association. I'll try to explain better and add some screeshot.

I need to be able to add payments to a selected user that may include one or more fees (for example John Smith is paying his membership fee and his wife fee and their 2 childhood fees, 1 annual standard fee + 1 partner's fee + 2 childhood fees). I think to create a priceset that use text/q.ty fields as it can simply add divverent fess as needed. 
But it cannot be used as give me the previous error.

Comment: please give me some screen shot - so it will be easy to help  - thanks